# calling a method inside async callback

Tags: methods, meteor

I am using kafka in my project using kafka-node package...

I have introduced a method and inside it i am trying to use a kafka module for eg:

```
Meteor.methods
  kafka: (topic, message) ->
    if(Meteor.isServer)
      message = JSON.stringify(message)
      kafka = Meteor.npmRequire 'kafka-node'
      HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer
      Client = kafka.Client
      client = new Client
      producer = new HighLevelProducer(client)
      payloads =[{topic: topic, messages: [message]}]
      producer.on 'ready', ->
        producer.send payloads, (error,data) ->
          if not error
            HighLevelConsumer = kafka.HighLevelConsumer
            Client = kafka.Client
            client = new Client('localhost:2181')
            topics = [ { topic: topic } ]
            options =
              autoCommit: true
              fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000
              fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024
            consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options)
            consumer.on 'message',(message) ->
              console.log message.value
              #Meteor.call 'saveMessage', message.value, (error,data) -> 

              return
            consumer.on 'error', (err) ->
              console.log 'error', err
              return
      producer.on 'error', (err) ->
        console.log 'error', err
```

Everything was fine until i decided to use meteor.call and call a method to save that message..
It gives me this error.

> Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks
>   that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment

I tried encapsulating it inside Fiber, used Meteor.wrapAsync(), Neither helped, 
Please guys can you help me, i am having difficult time solving this issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using node style callbacks, you can use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` around the callback. For example:

```
let Sockets = new Mongo.Collection('connections');

function createConnection (name) {
  check(name, String);
  let socket = net.connect(23, '192.168.1.3', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
    Sockets.upsert({ name: name }, { $set: { status: 'connected' } });
  }));
}
```